# Connection in android development

Tags: android

I have some connection problem when i am using the SAXParser. Someone says that the solution is setting up the user-permission internat but it does not work.

However, I use the strict mode code and the problems are solved.

I want to know why it can fix them.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

> http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/
>
> http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/